# why my VS code live sass compiler compiling separate css files?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am newbie in web development. So, the problem i am facing is my vs code live sass compiler compiling  separate CSS files but i want all my imported CSS files to be compiled in main.css file. Some screenshot maybe helps you to understand my problem.[image: imported scss files]

[image: save location]

Comment: prefix your partials with underscore, `_base.scss`?

Comment: Sir plz look at the images? i created all the sub SCSS files with like this _base.scss., _functions.scss

Comment: in the images it look more like a dash "-"  and not underscore "_"

Comment: Thank you sir my problem has been solved. Thanks for your kind help sir. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't put " _ " before the partials.